# Python - member function behaves differently when called within class

Tags: python, class

I am using a class member function that has a different effect when called within the class in which it is defined than when it is called externally.

```
def getLexid(self, senseKey):
    lexid = ""
    senseKeyParts = senseKey.split("%")
    if len(senseKeyParts) > 1:
        sense_number = senseKeyParts[1]
        # System.out.print("sense number: " + sense_number + '\n');
        senseNumParts = sense_number.split(":")
        if len(senseNumParts) > 1:
            lexid = senseNumParts[1]

    print("lexid:",lexid,"|")

    return lexid
```

here is its internal call:

```
def getLexname(self, senseKey):
    lexname = ""
    lexid = self.getLexid(senseKey).strip()
    print("Getting lexname with lexid:",senseKey,"(",lexid,")")
    print("Getting lexname with lexid:",senseKey.strip(),"(",lexid.strip(),")")
```

When I call getLexname externally:

```
wordnet_obj = wordnet.WordNet()
lexname = wordnet_obj.getLexname('forester%1:18:00::')
```

I get:

```
lexid: 18 |
Getting lexname with lexid: forester%1:18:00:: ( 18 )
Getting lexname with lexid: forester%1:18:00:: ( 18 )
```

The result gets padded with spaces and .strip() does not seem to have an effect.
However when I call getLexid externally:

```
wordnet_obj = wordnet.WordNet()
lexid2 = wordnet_obj.getLexid('forester%1:18:00::')
print("lexid2:",lexid2)
```

I get, as expected:

```
('lexid:','18')
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It's `print` that's adding the spaces, why don't you look at what is *actually* returned?

Comment: Which version of Python is this? Are you performing any `__future__` imports anywhere?

Comment: You are using Python 2, and using `from __future__ import print_function` there, but not when you are using `wordnet_obj.getLexid('forester%1:18:00::')`, where you are printing a *tuple*. In the other places you are calling the `print()` function which adds spaces between the arguments, you'd get the same if you used `print 'lexid2:', lexid2` in the 'externally' case.

Comment: thanks all - yep, understanding the print in the differing contexts did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are seeing the behavior of [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print):

> Print objects to the text stream file, separated by sep and followed by end. sep, end and file, if present, must be given as keyword arguments

By default the separator (sep) is one space single space.

In your example you are comparing the output of two different print statements `print('prefix', '18')` and `print('(', '18', ')')`.

From your example out bit for the external call I gather that you are using Python 3. For Python 3 you get:

```
>>> print('prefix', '18')  # This differs from your example maybe you had another pair of parentheses?
prefix 18
>>> print('(', '18', ')')  # Note the spaces around the number.
( 18 )
```

You can change the behavior by specifying an empty separator:

```
>>> print('(', '18', ')', sep='')
(18)
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation; the separator specification very helpful